# python symbol %u and %o

Tags: python, octal

I'm new to programming and trying to figure out what the % symbol does in print statements with different letters. I understand almost all of these accept for what the %u does. It seems like it just prints 538 as an integer. I saw that preceding the print statement with a 'u' prints in unicode but I don't know whether or not it applies with %u.

```
print "In honor of the election I present %d" % 538.0 # integer
print "In honor of the election I present %o" % 538.0 # octal
print "In honor of the election I present %u" % 538.0 # ?
print "In honor of the election I present %x" % 538.0 # lowercase hexadecimal
print "In honor of the election I present %X" % 538.0 # uppercase hexadecimal
print "In honor of the election I present %e" % 538.0 # exponential
print "In honor of the election I present %i" % 538.0 # integer
```

Output is below:

```
In honor of the election I present 538
In honor of the election I present 1032 *emphasized text*
In honor of the election I present 538 *emphasized text*
In honor of the election I present 21a
In honor of the election I present 21A
In honor of the election I present 5.380000e+02
In honor of the election I present 538
```

I'm also having a little trouble with `%o` for this number. I just learned what printing as an octal does and I figured it would output `132` (`538 --> 8^3 = 512 *(1) + 26, 8^1 = 8*(3) + 2, 8^0 = 1*(2)`), but output is `1032`. Where does the 0 come from?

Comment: The 0 is because there's 0 times 8^2 = 64 in that number. Octal 132 would be 2 * 8^0 + 3 * 8^1 + 1 * 8^2.

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), `%u` is an

> Obsolete type – it is identical to `'d'`.

`%o` tells `print` to interpret `538` as base-10 and convert it to octal. 538 base 10 (538<sub>10</sub>) is 1032 in octal (1032<sub>8</sub>):

```
1 * 8^3 + 0 * 8^2 + 3 * 8^1 + 2 * 8^0
= 512 + 0 + 24 + 2
= 538
```

It shows `1032`, because those are the appropriate coefficients of 8<sup>n</sup>. The `0` corresponds to 8<sup>2</sup>. If you left it out, you'd have 132<sub>8</sub> = 1 * 64 + 3 * 8 + 2 = 90<sub>10</sub>, not 538<sub>10</sub>

So, nothing weird there.